# count null values and group results

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

### Problem

i want to count null values and group the results but it gives me wrong values

```
String jpql = "select c.commande.user.login, (select count(*) 
from Designation c 
WHERE c.commande.commandeTms IS NOT EMPTY 
AND c.etatComde = 0) AS count1, 
    (select count(*) 
    from Designation c WHERE c.commande.commandeTms IS EMPTY ) AS count2  
    from Designation c GROUP BY c.commande.user.login";
```

---

I have got these results :

```
user1  user2
   10    10
    0     0
```

But I should have these ones :

```
user1  user2
    4     2
    3     1
```

**Sample data:**

table Commande

```
idComdeComm, commandeTms_idComndeTms, user_idUser

      6,                 17                  2
      8,                 NULL                2
     10,                 28                  2
     12,                 NULL                2
     14,                 NULL                2
     16,                 NULL                2
     21,                 NULL               19
     23,                 NULL               19
     25,                 26                 19
     31                  NULL               19
```

table designation

```
idDesignation, designation, etatComde, commande_idComdeComm
5,             'fef',         0,            6
7,             'ferf',        0,            8
9,             'hrhrh',       0,           10
11,            'ujujuju',     0,           12
13,            'kikolol',     0,           14
15,            'ololo',       0,           16
20,            'gdfgfd',      0,           21
22,            'gdfgfdd',     0,           23
24,            'nhfn',        0,           25
30,            'momo',        0,           31
```

table user

```
idUser, login,      password, profil
1,      'moez',     '***',    'admin'
2,      'user1',    '**',     'comm'
3,      'log',      '**',      'log'
4,      'mo',       '*',      'comm'
19,     'user2',    '*',      'comm'
```

table Commande TMS

```
idComndeTms, etatOperationNumCMD, numeroComndeTms
      17,        '',                 3131
      26,        '',                 2525
      28,        '',                 3333
```

Comment: You have show us the results.  You need to show us the data in the table too.

Comment: `IS NOT EMPTY `?? you mean `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: yes because IS NOT NULL gives me 0

Comment: Please add a sample of your table. Include all the columns that participate in the query.

Comment: i can't add an image of my database i need 10 reputations and i'm new

Comment: when i remove group by i got the right values but i want to have result by user

Comment: Cut and paste the SQL DDL and select * of input  tables. PS Your query returns columns count1 & 2 but your tables have user1 & 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting Null values in JPQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376952/counting-null-values-in-jpql)