# Counting Null values in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

i want to count null values in JPQL but count (case when "column" is null then.. end) doesn't work it work only on MYSQL ,i don't want to use count(*)  what is the solution  ??

```
String jpql ="select c.commande.user.login ,count(CASE WHEN c.commande.commandeTms is Null THEN 1 else 0 END) AS count1   from Designation c GROUP BY c.commande.user.login";
```

[here my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284393/count-null-values-and-group-results)

Comment: so what makes you think it only works on MySQL? which DBMS have you tried? what error are you getting?

Comment: because correct values are displaying only when i use mysql if i try with JPQL it display 0 as result

Answer (score 1):

Here you go : I have used CriteriaBuilder to count them ... as a result, you get a List of Tuple containing the user login and count elements ... you may want to change names and "count cases" according to your needs :

```
public List<Tuple> test() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
    Root<Designation> designation = cq.from(Designation.class);

    Join<Designation, Commande> commande = designation.join("commande");
    Join<Commande, User> user = commande.join("user");

    Expression expr = commande.get("commandeTms");

    cq.multiselect(user.get("login").alias("login"), 
            cb.sum(cb.<Long>selectCase().when(expr.isNotNull(), 1L).otherwise(0L)).alias("NotNull"),
            cb.sum(cb.<Long>selectCase().when(expr.isNull(), 1L).otherwise(0L)).alias("Null"));
    cq.groupBy(user.get("login"));

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: no i want to use count (case) because i have mutiple count

Comment: @JBNizet updated ... Moez Latrach, maybe you should update your question with an example of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Ok, i took my own time to do some unit testing before submitting an answer ... i have edited my answer

Comment: thank you Pras for your answer but i tried another simpler solution and it resolved my problem.

Comment: I created another Boolean attribute in my table which is true when the attribute "commandeTms" is not null ("commandeTms" is the attribute that i use it in my old count (case) above) so i count  directly from this new attribute when it is true

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` aggregate function for this case

```
String jpql ="SELECT c.commande.user.login, SUM(CASE WHEN c.commande.commandeTms IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1 FROM Designation c GROUP BY c.commande.user.login";
```